# Selenium XPATH or CSS to select a checkbox with the specified text from a html table I am getting four checkboxes selected

Tags: css, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select a checkbox from a HTML table of columns. I would like to select the checkbox which has the text "CLEAN_AUDIT" for Name
My XPATH is selecting 4 checkboxes CLEAN_AUDIT for Name, DOB, Address, Phone:

An example of how the table looks on the page is:

```
Table Header:             field        variable
               checkbox | Time_STAMP  | DOB
               checkbox | Time_STAMP  | Address
               checkbox | Clean_AUDIT | Name
               checkbox | Clean_AUDIT | Address
               checkbox | Clean_AUDIT | DOB
               checkbox | Clean_AUDIT | Phone
               etc...
```

I would like to select the 1 checkbox:

- Clean_AUDIT for Name

My XPATH is selecting 4 checkboxes:

- Clean_AUDIT for Name
- Clean_AUDIT for Address
- Clean_AUDIT for DOB
- Clean_AUDIT for Phone

The third column in the table is the Variable column.  It has Name in this one and I need the field from the 2nd column which is the Field column.

How do I build the XPATH to find the 3rd column which has "Name" and the 2nd column which has "Clean_AUDIT"

In my next test I could find "Address" which has "Clean_AUDIT"

My XPATH which finds all Clean_AUDIT for all of the Variables is:

```
//table[@id="reporting_add_report_tab_manual_ct_fields_avail"]//div[(text()="CLEAN_AUDIT")]/preceding::td[1]//input
```

I need to include Name in there somehow so I can find the correct Clean_Audit which i want.

The sample HTML is (I have shortened it otherwise it will be too long to paste here:

```
<table id="reporting_add_report_tab_manual_ct_fields_avail" class="GLKP2TGBJE" cellspacing="0" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingfocus="true" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingblur="true">
<thead aria-hidden="false">
    <colgroup>
        <tbody style="">
            <tr class="GLKP2TGBCD GLKP2TGBJD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0">
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD GLKP2TGBED GLKP2TGBKD">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-500" style="outline-style:none;">
                        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD GLKP2TGBKD">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-501" style="outline-style:none;">USN</div>
                </td>
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD GLKP2TGBOD GLKP2TGBKD">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-502" style="outline-style:none;" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="GLKP2TGBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="52">
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD GLKP2TGBED">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-552" style="outline-style:none;">
                        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-553" style="outline-style:none;">CLEAN_AUDIT</div>
                </td>
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD GLKP2TGBOD">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="GLKP2TGBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="20">
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD GLKP2TGBED">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-552" style="outline-style:none;">
                        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-553" style="outline-style:none;">EXPANDED_CLEAN_AUDIT</div>
                </td>
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD GLKP2TGBOD">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">Name</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="GLKP2TGBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="21">
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDE GLKP2TGBED">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-552" style="outline-style:none;">
                        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDE">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-553" style="outline-style:none;">CATEGORY</div>
                </td>
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDE GLKP2TGBOD">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">Name</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="GLKP2TGBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="62">
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD GLKP2TGBED">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-552" style="outline-style:none;">
                        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-553" style="outline-style:none;">CLEAN_AUDIT</div>
                </td>
                <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD GLKP2TGBOD">
                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-554" style="outline-style:none;">DOB</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody style="display: none;">
            <tfoot style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true" />
```

Thanks,
Riaz

Comment: Use index in xpath. can you check below xpath 

(//table[@id="reporting_add_report_tab_manual_ct_fields_avail"]//div[(text()="CLEAN_AUDIT")]/preceding::td[1]//input)[1]

Comment: That highlights all of the CLEAN_AUDIT checkboxes.  I just need the one which has Name and then I can specify Address for my next test.  Thanks.

Comment: //table[@id="reporting_add_report_tab_manual_ct_fields_avail"]//div[text()="CLEAN_AUDIT"]/preceding::td[1]//input[1]

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED

```
WebElement test = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='reporting_add_report_tab_manual_ct_fields_avail']//div[(text()='CLEAN_AUDIT')]/following::div[(text()='Name')]/preceding::td[1]/preceding::td[1]//input"));
test.click();
```

It is **working** example. I have tested this snippet with example from original question.